# Cucumber result parser

Tags: cucumber

Is there any tool that parses the results produced after cucumber scenarios are run?

Why need this?

I'm currently working on a my own simple CI for own use. This CI is used to run cucumber tests (run by calabash-android) on multiple devices and keep the run outputs. Now, I want to add a feature to re-run the scenarios failed. This is necessary because, the application's some features strongly depend on external conditions like internet access, device specific things, etc.

To accomplish this task I need to parse the output of cucumber and find out the tests failed. Maybe, I'll even make some statistics on which scenarios fail the most, etc.

Any hints, ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cucumber has built-in support for re-running failed scenarios:

```
cucumber --help
 ...
 Use --format rerun --out features.txt to write out failing
 features. You can rerun them with cucumber @rerun.txt.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Maven, you could write a small plugin that reads the Cucumber output files.

I had written one that aggregates the different json result files in one single file:
https://github.com/vincent-fuchs/cucumber-results-aggregator-plugin

Maybe you could do something similar.